# Zimbra server - High CPU Utilization

Tags: zimbra, high-load

I have used Zimbra server a number of times and it's great, but each time I had to abandon it because of a CPU utilization issue. The mail servers I set up are commonly small organizations with only a few hundred emails a day max. The last time I used Zimbra (About 6 years ago now), I installed it on a VM with limited resources. What would happen is that even though there were close to 0 emails being processed, some Zimbra housecleaning process would start running and peg 2 processors at 100% for about 20 minutes per hour.

I wanted to know if anyone running Zimbra nowadays knows what I'm talking about or what your current experiences with it are. It seems that if it is running on a standalone machine with enough resources it's not an issue, but I need to run it on VMs or cheaper machines.

Thank You

Comment: That's probably a known issue. You should have considered analysing the output of `top`. If zmlogger is taking a lot of CPU, that's because you didn't install/activate logrotate. Read : https://forums.zimbra.org/viewtopic.php?t=57838